# How to use the text of a cell in the input of a function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say C4 contains this: ="[2DR_"& B4 &".xls]" and it displays 
2DR_4.xls
I want to use this text in another cell exemple: E4=(text of C4)Feuil1'!E140

And i want in return the calculations, not the text

Comment: Just put =C4 & "Feuil1'!E140"

Comment: but this return a text not the calculations

Comment: Do you want to lookup the value in the other spreadsheet? Is it open at this point?

Comment: NO: another exemple: lets say C4 contains this text : Sum(A4:A8) I want to write in C5 this: =(text of C4). and i want it to return the value of hte calculation not the text. Understand better ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to reference to another Excel file? Then I think you are looking for the indirect formula:

```
      =Indirect(c4&"Feuil1!E140")
```

Comment: NO: another exemple: lets say   C4 contains this text : Sum(A4:A8) I want to write in C5 this: =(text of C4).  Understand better ?

Comment: No, I don't understand what you are trying to do. Were do you want to use cell C5 for?

Comment: it s just a hazardous cell, I want to use the text of a cell in another cell's text function, after "="

Comment: and I want to return the calculations not a text

Comment: You are not giving an example that can calculate anything. Please provide more details to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONCATENATE`. So `E4` would look `=CONCATENATE(C4,'Feuil1'!E140)`

Comment: this returns the text not the calculations

Comment: @RabahAkrour you want to use the text, its in Your Q. You might wanna make the Q more understandeable ;) `I want to use this text in another cell...`